# Changing the default font size

Tags: fonts, size

Hey I have problems reading my mathematica notebooks due to the small fonts. I'd like to change their default values for the input and output. I already figured out that everything seems to be defined in core.nb but I couldn't find any definitions inside. It just states things like:

[image]

But I don't see any definition, also I couldn't find them in the FormatType Styles section that looks like:
[image]

An easy solution to my problem is to change the magnification but this is only possible in too huge steps.

I also played around with the Option Inspector, but I could't find any place that effetcs the font size of my input/output. Changing the FontSize in Global options also didn't change anything:
[image]
Any ideas? I know there are many similar threats already but I couldn't find a working answer. And I doubt that the solution has to be super complicated.

Edit: Just realized that the last way changes the fonts as expected but only inside the documentation center.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to set a magnification factor for the current notebook (at the bottom right of the window)  or all notebooks (via NotebookOptions>Display Options> Magnification)? I do that on a computer with a large high-resolution screen where the default also looks too small compared to other screens that I use. By setting magnification, at least the notebook remains portable between computers with different displays (only the magnification has to be adjusted, plots don't need to be re-done).

Comment: Yes actually I was searching for this (as I explained), but I couldn't figure out how to change it in smaller steps then the default ones in the menu. But changing this inside the global options helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look for "Magnification" in the option inspector. Set it for only that notebook or globally to anything you like. Works for me. I would not touch core.nb

Comment: You can use Ctrl + mouse wheel to change the magnification quickly and in relatively small steps.

Comment: I tried this already, it wasn't working. I have a Mac.